# Connecting to informix with 64 bit web asp application

Tags: c#, .net, driver, informix

I am currently trying to connect my web application to an IBM Informix server. From what I've seen, the only drivers I can find for .net are 32 bit. When I use these with my 64 bit application, it doesn't work and it says there is an architecture mismatch.

Is there a 64 bit driver anywhere? I cannot find it and IBM is absolutely no help. I also cannot change the server from 64 bit to 32 bit, since some of our other libraries are 64bit, and we would want to keep the 64 bit regardless.

Our only other idea for a solution is to make a new project, make it 32 bit, and make apis that we can call to get the data from that project.

Comment: It's worse than that - not only is the driver 32-bit, it targets ADO.NET 1.0. Use the OLEDB or ODBC drivers instead

Comment: To put it another way, when IBM bought Informix 20 years ago, they were interested in the customer contracts, not the product. And they definitely didn't care about making life easier for competitors like Microsoft. This isn't going to change now that they offloaded it to HCL

Comment: We tried using the ODBC drivers as well, but that is also 32 bit, and cannot be used with our 64 bit applciation. The driver doesn't show up in the 64 bit  ODBC config application either.

Comment: You should be able to find 64-bit Windows drivers for Informix from IBM.  What's harder is knowing where to go.  I'm tolerably certain there is a 64-bit ODBC driver in the 64-bit CSDK 4.50 (and almost certainly in 4.10 too).  You will need to download and install that, though.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! I left an answer in case anyone else has to deal with this nonsense.

Comment: I can ensure that there is a 64bit ODBC driver in CSDK 4.50, in fact, there is no 32bit version in 4.50... but is difficult to find the download from IBM website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the driver needed. Turns out a 64 bit one does exist, and I found it on this page:

https://www.ibm.com/account/reg/us-en/subscribe?formid=urx-19776&target=https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/dispatcher.do?source=ifxdl&S_PKG=410FC8dewin&lang=en_US

I have no idea why IBM makes it so hard to find this. I found it on a random github repository after googling @Jonathan Leffler 's comment "CSDK 4.50". Github I found it on was here: https://github.com/credativ/informix_fdw/issues/20

Added the driver as a 64 bit driver in ODBC settings, everything functioning now. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: I know it's not that easy to find, but here is an IBM link with up-to-date information about all the Informix CSDK versions available, including where to download it from. ('F' means 64-bit, 'T' means 32-bit)  'https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/informix-client-software-development-kit-client-sdk-and-informix-connect-system-requirements#windows'